# Why is the TextView appearing larger only in Galaxy Nexus?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a simple layout that consists of `TextView`s and it is displaying okay on all the other devices except Nexus 5 | API 6.x.

Here is how it's **supposed to** look like:(*Excuse the scaling of screenshot that I did for posting here*)

[image]

Here is how it looks like:

[image]

Now, you can see here that the *Following* Button is overlapping the `TextView`s. On other devices, the text is small and so there is no overlap. I haven't configured programmatically any property of the `TextView`s separately and it looks okay on many other devices. What could be causing such an issue?

The text on other devices is smaller than this one so that the button doesn't overlap. Nexus somehow is showing a larger text.

I have tried setting the text size to 12sp instead of dp with no success and also there isn't preference set in the phone to have a bigger text.

---

Here is the layout for reference:

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeStudentProfilefollowlayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearStudentProfiletotalfollower"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/lef_margin"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/otheruser_followers_label"
                            android:textColor="@color/header_follow_label_color"
                            android:textSize="12dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtStudentProfiletotalfollower"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_margin_1dp"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textColor="@color/header_follow_label_color"
                            android:textSize="12dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearStudentProfiletotalfollowing"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/lef_margin"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:text="@string/otheruser_following_label"
                            android:textColor="@color/header_follow_label_color"
                            android:textSize="12dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtStudentProfiletotalfollowing"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_margin_1dp"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textColor="@color/header_follow_label_color"
                            android:textSize="12dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearStudentProfiletotalvisit"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:text="@string/otheruser_views_label"
                            android:textColor="@color/header_follow_label_color"
                            android:textSize="12dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtStudentProfilevisit"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_margin_1dp"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textColor="@color/header_follow_label_color"
                            android:textSize="12dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnStudentProfilefollow"
                    style="@style/btnStyleFollwingView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_height"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:text="Follow"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you also post a picture for normal/expected case?

Comment: @azizbekian : Posted!

Comment: Do you think that's a font issue? It seems to me that's a screen size issue, you are not handling that case. Take a look at [autosizing `TextView`s](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview.html).

Answer (score 0):

Text size is not given in dp but in sp so use this -

```
android:textSize="12sp"
```

You can apply this approach -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="5"
>
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="@dimen/zeroDp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/rl1"
android:layout_weight="4"></RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="@dimen/zeroDp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rl2"
    android:layout_weight="1"></RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

inside rl2 define layout for your button , inside rl1 define followers layout

Comment: I have already mentioned in the question that I have tried with sp but there is no change :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not using dp for text-size in whole layout xml. 
If still overlapping; it may be due to device width which might be little less to fit your content. In that case try reducing text-size or you can use linear layout weight property to solve your problem.